# Scripting on an android tablet for simple text analytics and discrete simulation

Tags: android, ide

Which language/ide would you use for using an 8 inch Android tablet to process text-files and output result to file.

I tried Cloud 9 and also ssh-to my VPN, but an 8" is a bit small for doing that.

My requirements aren't that high:

- String manipulation including reqular expressions.
- Datastructures such as lists and maps would be desirable.
- Random numbers

Thanks for any suggestions!

(I'll be trying out Paul Laughton's BASIC! ... It's been decades since the last time i wrote antying stuff in QBasic, Amiga Basic and Casio basic, but it might work out for this purpose)

Update:
Tried basic! and looking forward to experimenting with the
Suggestions below.

**First impressions editing on an 8 inch tablet without bluetooth keyboard**

- BASIC 28 minutes: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=roSpa1L7uWI
- Ryby under 10 minutes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuK3quoLmSA
- Python, 11 minutes using QPython https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qd5VMDv5UL4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an IDE I think you can't go past [DroidEdit](http://www.droidedit.com/). It has a great minimal interface with file tabs and support for Dropbox & SFTP. As for language I prefer Python for all the tasks you've listed but DroidEdit has syntax support for 100+ languages.

DroidEdit can compile/run code remotely via SSH and pipe the results back. In addition it also supports [SL4A](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) to run various scripting languages directly on Android.

Comment: There haven't been any updates for a year but there are still active users. If you have specific issues I would suggest posting on the [newsgroup](http://groups.google.com/group/android-scripting).

Comment: Actually after I saw your videos there your question makes more sense. If you want to learn a language just stick with Ruboto or QPython as everything is packaged. DroidEdit and SL4A require more setup and assume a higher expertise level.

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere - 10 mins is not a bad start :)  And just to comment on your Python video, yes the whole Python2/3 thing is confusing for people starting out. I would recommend learning v3; I switched last year and it is much more widely supported now than when I started. The tipping point has probably passed and v2 will soon be end-of-life. For most purposes the differences are pretty [subtle](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/python-2-vs-python-3) and you will soon learn how to convert v2 examples to v3 code.

Answer (score 2):

[ruby-language](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) is a dynamic, open source programming language with a focus on simplicity and productivity. It has an elegant syntax that is natural to read and easy to write certainly allows you to meet and exceed the requirements that you have listed

**Ruboto IRB** allows interactive Ruby running on Android. Edit, save, and run scripts on the phone. Great for learning, prototyping, and small apps. Ruboto IRB taps the power of [JRuby](http://jruby.org) to open up the Android API.allows you to write and run scripts.

It's available on [play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ruboto.irb) but if you're confident with android programming you'd prefer to get started with ruboto-irb is to install a prebuilt binary package. These packages can be found at https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto-irb/tree/master/dist.

additional useful documentation:

- http://github.com/headius/ruboto-irb
- https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/wiki/Using-Ruboto-IRB-to-jump-start-development
- http://groups.google.com/group/ruboto
- http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/